# project.yaml synchronize error (not usable anymore)

Tags: craft3, projectconfig, project.yaml

I had a table field and created a new super table field to try something.
After that I removed my table field and gave my super table field the same handle like the old table field had.

I did it locally and synced it via git. 
After that I wanted to sync my project.yaml. 
I tried `./craft project-config/sync` and I got a error: `error: Getting unknown property: craft\fields\Table::contentTable`

I tried to remove the complete section on my production server but still no changes. At the moment I have no Idea what I could do…

Of course `./craft project-config/rebuild` works but then I have my old project.yaml

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it with a rebuilded project file locally.